# Hibernate Inheritance and Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, annotations

What is the proper way to have an abstract class A, inherited by abstract class B, inherited by class C using Hibernate and Spring Boot?

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance 
abstract class A{} 

@Entity
@Inheritance
abstract class B extends A{}

@Entity 
@Inheritance 
final class C entends B{}
```

The problem is I have an exception "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column something(from class A) does not exist". Are my annotations wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `@MappedSuperclass`? Also, entities shouldn't be `final`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the abstract class should not be an Entity. You cannot instanciate it. Try

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class B extends A {
}
```

```
@Entity
public class C extends B {
}
```

And, like he said, class C should not be final.